# Flyway: How to handle v1.x style versions (e.g 1.2.0.a) in migration filenames?

Tags: migration, flyway

Currently we are using Flyway 2.0.3 and finally do our homework to upgrade to the latest version of Flyway.

I am aware of the step to go to 2.3.0 first. With that step we adjust the version schema of Flyway.

Now I am looking for a way to migrate our sql migration files with the following naming pattern:

```
V1_2_0_a__AddFileDescription-oracle.sql
V1_2_0_b__ModifyFileDescription-oracle.sql
...
V1_3_0_a__DoSomeStuff-oracle.sql
```

With the drop of the support of non-number characters I receive the known error `com.googlecode.flyway.core.api.FlywayException: Invalid version containing non-numeric characters. Only 0..9 and . are allowed. Invalid version: 1.2.0.a`

Is there any best practice migration guild for that old version available?
Any suggestions are very welcome. Thanks,
J0er9

Update:
Renaming the migration files as suggested do not solve the issue. 
With renamed migration files the parsing of the sql files succeeds. But in the next step Flyway reads the already applied migrations from the meta data table ("schema_version" in my case). This fails because the old pattern version numbers are still present in the database. This ends up with

```
 org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Version may only contain 0..9 and . (dot). Invalid version: 1.2.0.a
at org.flywaydb.core.api.MigrationVersion.toBigInteger(MigrationVersion.java:258)
at org.flywaydb.core.api.MigrationVersion.tokenize(MigrationVersion.java:241)
at org.flywaydb.core.api.MigrationVersion.<init>(MigrationVersion.java:82)
at org.flywaydb.core.api.MigrationVersion.fromVersion(MigrationVersion.java:71)
at org.flywaydb.core.internal.schemahistory.JdbcTableSchemaHistory$2.mapRow(JdbcTableSchemaHistory.java:202)
at org.flywaydb.core.internal.schemahistory.JdbcTableSchemaHistory$2.mapRow(JdbcTableSchemaHistory.java:184)
at org.flywaydb.core.internal.jdbc.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:367)
at org.flywaydb.core.internal.schemahistory.JdbcTableSchemaHistory.refreshCache(JdbcTableSchemaHistory.java:184)
at org.flywaydb.core.internal.schemahistory.JdbcTableSchemaHistory.allAppliedMigrations(JdbcTableSchemaHistory.java:174)
at org.flywaydb.core.internal.info.MigrationInfoServiceImpl.refresh(MigrationInfoServiceImpl.java:131)
at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbValidate$2.call(DbValidate.java:138)
at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbValidate$2.call(DbValidate.java:126)
at org.flywaydb.core.internal.jdbc.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:74)
at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbValidate.validate(DbValidate.java:126)
at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.doValidate(Flyway.java:267)
```

Is there some kind of fixing logic in place? Or can this be achieved by Flyway.repair() call? If I understand repair() right, it would wipe the not longer available migrations from the meta data table. In my case the old migrations would not be longer available due to the renaming.

Answer (score 0):

Would changing `V1_2_0_a__Foo.sql` to `V1_2_0_10__Foo.sql` etc. not work for you?

Edit: if you have records from old versions in the database, then it is possible to rename scripts to the numeric pattern at the same time as UPDATEs to the schema history table to keep the two consistent. Although you would probably be better off re-baselining your production databases at this point and only considering the old migrations in lower environments.

Also, v2.0.3 is now six years old and there is no direct migration path to the current v6.1. Is there any particular reason you haven't upgraded to higher versions before now?

Comment: Unfortunately this does not solve my issue. I have tried that before but have double checked that again. After renaming the sql files Flyway fails while checking the still applied migrations. We have a lot of running installations in the wild, so I need to take care about that as well. I update my post with the details.

Comment: You may be able to patch up the schema history table directly so that it matches the already applied migrations again to get yourself out of a hole, but it's not a recommended strategy...